# Create Service Connection from Azure DevOps to GCP Artifact Registry

Tags: azure-devops, google-artifact-registry

Is there have any tutorials for creating a service account to GCP Artifact Registry?

i have tried this: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/creating-cicd-pipeline-vsts-kubernetes-engine
... but it is using GCP Container Registry

I do not imagine it should be much different but i keep on getting this:

`##[error]denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource`

BUT the service account i created has the permissions needed (albeit those roles are in beta). i even gave it a very elevated role and still getting this.

when i created the service connect i followed these steps from the documentation linked above:

- Docker Registry: `https://gcr.io/PROJECT_ID`, replacing `PROJECT_ID` with the name of your project (for example, `https://gcr.io/azure-pipelines-test-project-12345`).
- Docker ID: `_json_key`
- Password: Paste the content of `azure-pipelines-publisher-oneline.json.`
- Service connection name: `gcr-tutorial`

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. As @Mexicoder points out the service account needs the ArtifactRegistryWriter permission. In addition, the following wasn't clear to me initially:

- The service connection needs to be in the format: https://REGION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID (where region is something like 'us-west2')
- The repository parameter to the Docker task (Docker@2) needs to be in the form: PROJECT-ID/REPO/IMAGE

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the documentation for Container Registry.

my issue was with the repository name.

ALSO the main difference when using Artifact Registry is the permission you need to give the IAM service account. Use ArtifactRegistryWriter. StorageAdmin will be useless.